# Running a file in the same directory as the invoking Python module or script

Tags: python, file, process

How can I run a batch file with Python (in the same directory as the Python scripts)?

Note that the directory cannot be constant as it can be changed from one user to another.

Comment: take a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library for calling external commnads (like bat files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: @turbulencetoo, the only respect in which I'm not sure that's a dupe is inasmuch as finding the command to be run *relative to the Python source file's location* is an element of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out where your script is and assemble an absolute path:

```
import os
import subprocess

dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
cmd = os.path.join(dirname, 'mybatch_file')

subprocess.call(cmd)
```

#### In Steps

You can find out the name of script with:

```
__file__
```

Now make it an absolute path:

```
os.path.abspath
```

and get the directory it is in:

```
os.path.dirname
```

Finally, join this path with your batch file name:

```
os.path.join
```

before you feed it to:

```
subprocess.call
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it use subprocess module

```
from subprocess import call
comando = 'path_to_the_script'
call(comando, shell=True)
```